# users to own ther data in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

i want users to own their data but this is the error i keep getting
" Cannot resolve keyword 'merchant' into field. Choices are: date_added, id, order, order_id, product, product_id, quantity"

models.py

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class Product(models.Model):
   merchant=models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def users_homepage(request):
    itemsordered=OrderItem.objects.filter(merchant=request.user.merchant).order_by('date_added')
```

thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `OrderItem` has no `merchant` field, so you can not filter on this, or at least not directly. You can look "through" a relation with two consecutive underscores (`__`):

```
def users_homepage(request):
    itemsordered=OrderItem.objects.filter(
        product__merchant__user=request.user
    ).order_by('date_added')
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).